# How to return a specific attribute of an object from an axios Get request as functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm quite new at React/axios/js in general, so I apologize if it is a somewhat silly question,

I'm fetching multiple objects with multiple attributes each from an springboot API, for a simple table display, using axios to fecth the data. my problem is that i can only get the whole object with all attributes at once, i would like after getting the object trough the axios Get request, to separate each attribute from the object, and then export it to my table module, so i can properly display each on the corresponding table fields (name, age, and so on).

I was able to make it work using a class based approach, constructors and setStates, but i need to do it using hooks and as a functional component with React. i'll paste my current code.

The Axios request module

```
import axios from "axios";

const API_ADRESS = "http://localhost:8080/api/users";

const userDatax = axios.get(API_ADRESS).then((res) => {
  return { nome: res.data[0] };
});

console.log(userDatax);

export default userDatax;
```

now the the React module which i need  to display the object attributes as individual elements for the table display

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import userDatax from "../services/UserService";
import "./card.css";

const TabelaUsuarios = (props) => {
  const [usuario, setUsuario] = useState();

  console.log(userDatax);
  console.log(
    userDatax.then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    })
  );

  let DATARUX = userDatax.then((res) => {
    return res;
  });

  console.log(DATARUX);

  function callUseState() {
    setUsuario(DATARUX);
  }

  return (
    <div className="card">
      <h1 className="text-center">USUARIOS CADASTRADOS</h1>
      <div>
        <table className="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>ID </td>
              <td>NOME </td>
              <td>SOBRENOME </td>
              <td>EMAIL</td>
              <button onClick={callUseState}>change user</button>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <td></td>

            {
              <tr>
                <td>{usuario}</td>
                <td>{usuario}</td>
                <td>{usuario}</td>
                <td>{usuario}</td>
              </tr>
            }
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TabelaUsuarios;
```

oh, and for reference here are the objects i'm fetching from the java springboot API

> public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
> RepositorioUsuarios.save(new User("Roger","Waters","rgrwaterspf@gmail.com"));
> RepositorioUsuarios.save(new User("Peter","Gabriel","sledgehammer@gmail.com"));
> RepositorioUsuarios.save(new User("Rick","Wakeman","srick.wake77@gmail.com"));
> RepositorioUsuarios.save(new User("Chuck","Berry","MrChuck10@gmail.com"));

Thanks in advance for any guidance, I'm quite new at coding and i'm trying to improve myself as fast as I can, I will be grateful for any tips or methods on this particular problems, cheers everyone!

I've tried to use the Map method on the object to map all elements without success, also I've tried Destructuring the object, once i've fetched the data using the axios get request, but even when I set a variable to the fetch result, I could not work with the variable as an normal object or array, it always an axios promise package, i've tried to look on axios documentation on how to better deal with requests but still with not success, I'm hoping for a solution on how to handle the data request and access the individual elements and attributes of the object.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the field of your response this way:

```
usuario.fieldName
```

So it would look like this

```
{
     <tr>
        <td>{usuario.fieldOne}</td>
        <td>{usuario.fieldTwo}</td>
        <td>{usuario.fieldThree}</td>
        <td>{usuario.fieldFour}</td>
    </tr>
}
```